# C++11 iterator and the scope of a returned std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, iterator, ranged-loops

**Problem**

As I understand it, when a `std::unique_ptr` is returned from a function into an rvalue, its lifetime should encompass the statement that consumes that rvalue. But compiling with gcc 6.4.1, the return value from `Foo::iterator()` goes out of scope before the *start* of the C++11 foreach statement in function `crashing_version()`. As shown in the output below, the destructor is called just after the containing expression is evaluated. Is this a bug in gcc, or bad programming practice?

**Use Case**

The goal of this pattern is to make iteration available without exposing the private vectors. This seems to require some object like `Foo::Iterator` because there are two separate lists to iterate.

```cpp
#include <iostream>                                                                        
#include <memory>                                                                          
#include <vector>                                                                          

class Foo {                                                                            
    /* Goal: allow iteration without exposing the vector objects. */    
    std::vector<int> _list0;                                                           
    std::vector<int> _list1;                                                           

public:                                                                                
    class Iterator {                                                                   
        int _list_id;                                                                  
        Foo& _foo;                                                                     

    public:                                                                            
        Iterator(int list_id, Foo& foo) : _list_id(list_id), _foo(foo) {}              
        ~Iterator() {                                                                  
            std::cout << "~Iterator(): Destroying iterator of the "                    
                      << (_list_id == 0 ? "even" : "odd") << " list\n";                
        }                                                                              

        std::vector<int>::iterator begin() {                                           
            if (_list_id == 0)                                                         
                return _foo._list0.begin();                                            
            else                                                                       
                return _foo._list1.begin();                                            
        }                                                                              

        std::vector<int>::iterator end() {                                             
            if (_list_id == 0)                                                         
                return _foo._list0.end();                                              
            else                                                                       
                return _foo._list1.end();                                              
        }                                                                              
    };                                                                                 

    void add(int i) {                                                                  
        if ((i % 2) == 0)                                                              
            _list0.push_back(i);                                                       
        else                                                                           
            _list1.push_back(i);                                                       
    }                                                                                  

    std::unique_ptr<Iterator> iterator(int list_id) {                                  
        return std::make_unique<Iterator>(list_id, *this);                             
    }                                                                                  
};                                                                                     

void working_version() {                                                               
    Foo foo;                                                                           

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                                       
        foo.add(i);                                                                    

    /* This works because the unique_ptr stays in scope through the loop. */       
    std::cout << "Valid iterator usage: \n";                                           
    std::unique_ptr<Foo::Iterator> evens = foo.iterator(0);                            
    for (int i : *evens)                                                               
        std::cout << i << "\n";                                                        
}                                                                                      

void crashing_version() {                                                              
    Foo foo;                                                                           

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                                       
        foo.add(i);                                                                    

    /* Crash! The unique_ptr goes out of scope before the loop starts. */              
    std::cout << "Corrupt iterator usage: \n";                                         
    for (int i : *foo.iterator(1))                                                     
        std::cout << i << "\n";                                                        
}                                                                                      

int main() {                                                                           
    working_version();                                                                 
    crashing_version();                                                                

    return 0;                                                                          
}
```

Program output:

```
Valid iterator usage: 
0
2
4
6
8
~Iterator(): Destroying iterator of the even list

Corrupt iterator usage: 
~Iterator(): Destroying iterator of the odd list
1
3
5
7
9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `for(range_declaration:range_expression)` expression is equivalent (in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)) to:

```
{
  auto && __range = range_expression ;
  for (
    auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr;
    __begin != __end;
    ++__begin)
  {
    range_declaration = *__begin;
    loop_statement
  }
}
```

[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), with variables starting with `__` existing only as exponsition.

We substitute:

```
for (int i : *evens)                                                               
    std::cout << i << "\n";
```

and we get:

```
{
  auto && __range = *evens;
  for (
    auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr;
    __begin != __end;
    ++__begin)
  {
    int i = *__begin;
    std::cout << i << "\n";                                                        
  }
}
```

we can now clearly see your bug.  Your unique ptr lasts as long as the `__range` line, but after dereferencing the unique ptr goes away, and we have a dangling reference in `__range`.

---

You can fix this with a little helper:

```
template<class Ptr>
struct range_ptr_t {
  Ptr p;
  auto begin() const {
    using std::begin;
    return begin(*p);
  }
  auto end() const {
    using std::end;
    return end(*p);
  }
};
template<class Ptr>
range_ptr_t<std::decay_t<Ptr>> range_ptr( Ptr&& ptr ) {
  return {std::forward<Ptr>(ptr)};
}
```

now we do:

```
for (int i : range_ptr(evens))                                                               
    std::cout << i << "\n";
```

and we no longer have the unique ptr dying on us.

It might be a good idea to extend the lifetime of `range_expression` to the body of the `for(:)` loop, as this problem leads to other issues (like when chaining range adapters) that end up with similarly annoying workarounds.

Minimal testcase:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> foo() {
  return std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>( std::vector<int>{ 1, 2, 3} );
}


int main() {
  for (int x : range_ptr(foo())) {
    std::cout << x << '\n';
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, because of how observable this behavior is, extending the lifetime of temporaries within the range expression would be a breaking change.  Which makes it less of a good idea than the first impression would give.

Comment: I don't totally understand why the `range_ptr_t` stays in scope. Is it because `__range` acquires the actual instance of `range_ptr_t`, since its type is directly compatible with the (hidden) iterator spec?

Comment: @ByronHawkins `__range` captures `range_ptr_t` because the `range_expression` is a prvalue of type `range_ptr_t`. `__range` captures *exactly* whatever `range_expression` evaluates as, and follows the `auto&&` rules (which in this case make it an rvalue reference that binds to the prvalue instantiated temporary, which is then reference lifetime extended). In your case, it binds to the return value of unary `*` from a `unique_ptr`, which is not a temporary, so its lifetime is not extended. Now, `range_ptr_t` works as a `range_expression` because it has a `begin` and `end` that return iterators.

Comment: @ByronHawkins And using the word "iterator" to refer to the concept or "ranges" is a bad idea.  Iterator is a defined concept in C++, don't reuse it for a different meaning.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure, it will be painful.  But the stupidity of this issue is large enough the break should be considered.  Either that, or we need a full-on attack on lifetime extension and permit code to indicate lifetime dependencies so `auto&& p = *std2::make_unique_ptr<foo>();` also extends the lifetime of the temporary `unique_ptr` because `operator*` is marked up to indicate that the lifetime of the return value depends on the lifetime of `*this`.  Which seems more radical.  The current situation is simply a screw up in [tag:C++11].

Comment: Aside from backward-compatibility concerns, it seems like there's nothing to *lose* by extending the lifetime across directly related consumers. For example, if an application is so tight on memory that it needs objects to expire asap, that can easily be coded the old-fashioned way (and probably should be in that case). Coming from a GC environment, some of these lifetime factors are really quite a surprise--and not so much the fun kind.

Comment: @byron lifetime is more than about memory; it is side effects, resources of all kinds, locks, etc.  It is deterministic cleanup.  It does mean you must track who owns what at all times, with smart containers/pointers doing away with some of the overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Your code exhibits undefined behavior. gcc, msvc, and clang all behave the same; the iterators' destructor runs before anything is output.

The range-based for loop in this case can be treated as a convenient way of caching a function call, so your code is equivalently this<sup>*</sup> ([stmt.ranged]):

```
auto&& range = *foo.iterator(1);
for (auto __begin = range.begin(), __end = range.end(); __begin!=__end; ++__begin){
        int i = *__begin;                                                     
        std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

By de-referencing the unique_ptr, `range` becomes a reference to the underlying `Iterator`, which then immediately goes out of scope.

<sup>*these rules change slightly in C++17 so that `__begin` and `__end` don't need to be the same type</sup>